# I have the following code. I can't get my navigation to hide after I successfully got it to show

Tags: jquery

I have the following code. I can't get my navigation to hide after I successfully got it to show:

```
    $(".main-nav").hide();


    $(".menu-btn-container .menu-toggle").click(function() {
        $(".main-nav").show();
        $(".menu-btn-container").append("<a href='#' class='menu-toggle-off'><span class='menu-icon'><i class='fa fa-times'</i></span></a>");
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $(".menu-btn-container .menu-toggle-off").click(function() {
        $(".main-nav").hide();
    });`
```

Comment: could you post the html too ?

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a handler to an element with `$(someSelector).click(function(){......});` the target element **must be present on the page when you call the function to bind the handler**

In your case, the binding function is called on page load when `'.menu-toggle-off'` does not yet exist (doesnt get added until you click `.menu-toggle`). You need to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind the handler to a different element that **is** present on load and let it listen for clicks on the desired elements like:

$(document).on('click','.menu-toggle-off',function() {
        $(".main-nav").hide();
  });`

Note that `document` used here will work but you should really use an element closer to the target element in the hierarchy.